# How do I load Fragments into my SlidingPaneLayout menu?

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I'm a newbie, so please bear with me. I've implemented a SlidingPaneLayout in my app. However, in the example I followed it populated the menu fragment with an array of strings. I think it was just as an example. How do I populate the menu fragment with links to the fragments I want to give my users access to?

I have a `menu` list with the names of the fragments I'd like to display, but it doesn't seem to be implemented.

Here is the code from my menu fragment:

```js
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    public static final String[] items = { "Item 1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Item 2: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Item 3: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Item 4: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Item 5: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Item 6: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "Item 7: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" };

    ListFragmentItemClickListener iItemClickListener;

    /** An interface for defining the callback method */
    public interface ListFragmentItemClickListener {
        /**
         * This method will be invoked when an item in the ListFragment is
         * clicked
         */
        void onListFragmentItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    /** A callback function, executed when this fragment is attached to an activity */
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            /** This statement ensures that the hosting activity implements ListFragmentItemClickListener */
            iItemClickListener = (ListFragmentItemClickListener) activity;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity.getBaseContext(),"Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_list, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {

        /**
         * Invokes the implementation of the method onListFragmentItemClick in
         * the hosting activity
         */
        iItemClickListener.onListFragmentItemClick(view, position);

    }

}
```

Here is the code from the `menu` list:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ehr"
            android:title="@string/ehr_short" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_protocols"
            android:title="@string/protocols" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your menu in an XML file and then handle events using menu event handlers. [This example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) should help you.

The main idea is that when you use the Android Menu interface components you get access to event handlers like `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` which allow you to control your UI flow.